# Codeigniter 3.0 not working on Bluehost

Tags: php, codeigniter, bluehost

When I run Codeigniter 3.0 application at local server, it works fine. However, when I uploaded it to Bluehost, it doesn't work.

Codeigniter itself is working but I get a Codeingiter 404 and not an Apache 404 - the page gets style, etc etc.

I think the problem has to do with Codeigniter 3.0 and Bluehost, since I uploaded 2 different apps to BH.

When I use Codeigniter 2.x, everything works fine.

Comment: * I will post my .htaccess soon, I'm on mobile now. But if anyone already knows of this issue and how to solve it. Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Starting with CodeIgniter 3.0, all class filenames (libraries, drivers, controllers and models) must be named in a **Ucfirst-like** manner or in other words - they must start with a **capital letter**.

Controllers:

`application/controllers/welcome.php` to `application/controllers/Welcome.php`

Models:

`application/models/misc_model.php` to `application/models/Misc_model.php`

Source: [Classes file naming Conversion in CodeIgniter](http://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/installation/upgrade_300.html#step-2-update-your-classes-file-names)

> **Note** that this **DOES NOT affect directories, configuration files, views, helpers, hooks and anything else** - it is **only applied to classes**.
>
> You must now follow just **one simple rule - class names in Ucfirst and everything else in lowercase**.

and `.htaccess` should be

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L] 
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Thanks Abdulla! I changed the case on the classes files and it worked perfectly.

However, how do you explain it working on my computer and having this problem only  after I upload it to Bluehost? (I didn't test it in any other hosting provider).

Best regards!

Comment: Sorry I forgot ;) Done.

Answer (score 0):

I hope the following .htaccess will work for you:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|resources|robots\.txt)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: Arif, thanks for your answer.. It still doesn't work. I'm going to test what ABdulla said bellow.

Best regards